# Class names with Verbs

Tags: naming, clean-code

So I am reading *Clean Code*. In the *Meaningful Names* chapter, they lay down a rule of no verbs in class names. However in the *Adding Meaningful Context* section of that chapter, on page 29, he uses a class name `GuessStatisticsMessage`.

How can we validate the use of **Guess** in a class name, even though it is a verb?

Comment: [Guess is a noun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/guess) (see definition 3). That class could simply be a message about the statistics of guesses, but we'd need more context to know if that is the case.

Comment: Does it really say "no verbs in class names", or "no verbs *as* class names"? Nouns can very well be composed of other word classes, such as "know-it-all". Besides, *Guess* might very well *be* a noun: a Message about your best guess of some statistics.

Comment: @8bittree I re-checked the book (listings 2-1 and 2-2) and it indeed looks like guess is used as a noun over there. `printGuessStatistics(char candidate, int count)` --> "how good was our guess at `candidate` char"

Answer (score 0):

Here,Guess is a noun being used here.As pointed out by @Killan Foth in the comment section,it should be no verbs as class names.
There are cases in english where a verb behaves as noun.
In the context,without looking the function definition, Guess might be indicating the how probable the guess was right or wrong.